# Cluster as a transcendence basis of the field of rational functions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cluster-algebra

Let $P$ be a free multiplicative abelian group of a finite rank $m$ with generators $g_1,\dots,g_m$. Field $F$ of rational functions in $n$ independent variables is set to be the ambient field in our case with the coefficient in the field of fractions of the integer group ring $\mathbb{Z}P =\mathbb{Z}[g_{1}^{\pm1},\dots,g_{m}^{\pm1}]$. Next, we have a definition of a *seed*:

*A seed in* $F$ *is a pair* $\sum=$(**x**,$\tilde{B}$) *where* **x**$=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ *is a transcendence basis of $F$ over the field of fractions of* $\mathbb{Z}P$ *and* $\tilde{B}$ is an $ n \times (n+m)$ *integer matrix whose principal part is sign-skew-symmetric*

In what follows **x** is called a cluster, and its elements $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ are calledd cluster variables. What I am not sure about is how do we know that **x** is a transcendence basis of $F$ over the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}P$? So I think that $\mathbb{Z}P$ $\subset F$(?). So I first need to show that **x**  is algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Z}P$? And that the extension $\mathbb{Z}P(x_i;i\in \{ 1, \dots, n\}) \subset F$ is algebraic (here, field of fractions of a polynomial ring $k[x_i;i\in I]$ is denoted $k(x_i;i\in I)$ for some field $k$)? Is that correct? If so, I am not really sure how do this. I would appreciate some hints.

Comment: $P = \Bbb{Z}^m$, its group ring is $\Bbb{Z}[X^{\Bbb{Z}^m}]=\Bbb{Z}[x_1,x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_m,x_m^{-1}]$ which is an integral domain with fraction field $K=\Bbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ so if $F=\Bbb{Q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ then a $K$-transcendence basis is $x_{m+1},\ldots,x_n$. What do you do with your matrix $B $ ?

Comment: @reuns apologies for a late reply and thank you for you comment! To make sure I understand this correctly: so we have that $K \subset F$. If we take any non-zero polynomial $f$ over $K$ in $n-(m+1)$ variables we must have that $f(x_{m+1},\dots,x_n) \neq 0$ since $F$ is an integral domain and $K \subset F$. Moreover, since $x_{m+1},\dots,x_n$ are algebraic over $Q$ then the finite extension $Q(x_1,\dots,x_m)(x_{m+1},\dots,x_n)$ is algebraic. Thus, $x_{m+1},\dots,x_n$ is a transcendence basis over $K$. Is that the correct logic?

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $Q$